# How to flag "explain this textbook algorithm" questions?

Tags: support

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335402/topological-sorting-c ([<10k link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKTmd.png))

Note: Question is now deleted, but it was not a "explain this code to me" question, it was "I don't understand this (textbook algorithm) please explain"

My belief is that this question is "not about programming as defined on help center". It's possibly a math question, "explain this algorithm to me".

My thought was, this could potentially be migrated to "CS Theory" stack exchange. But that was not one of the options.

A commenter suggested that it should just be flagged as "too broad".

I ended up flagging it as "request for off-site resource ... *tutorial*".

Was that correct?

Comment: @Trobbins: So it wasn't actually a "${code dump}" question, it was "explain this (named) algorithm" to me. Maybe it is a "personal tutoring request" as described in second answer in that question.

Comment: That was my presumption :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is essentially "Explain Tarjan's Algorithm to me", which I think can be closed as "Too Broad." There are all sorts of things you could explain about the algorithm:

1. How it works (pseudocode + explanation) -- this alone would be a very long answer
2. Implementation considerations (e.g. data structures)
3. Asymptotic runtime and space analysis

... and so on. The OP needs to narrow the question down to perhaps a specific part of the algorithm they didn't understand or were having trouble implementing to make the question on-topic.

While I'm not active on CS Theory, I would imagine they wouldn't be thrilled to have such a vague question migrated to their site. Since this isn't a direct request for an off-site tutorial, I would prefer the "too broad" close reason to the "off-topic... resource request" one.